# Compute min for values <0?

Tags: r, raster

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
r2[] <- runif(ncell(r2)) / 2
r3[] <- runif(ncell(r3)) * 1.5
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)
```

I can use `min` and `max` to get the minimum and maximum of s

```
 res=max(s); res=min(s)
```

What I need is take max for only values > 0
and min for only values < 0.

if a pixel has all values < 0, return NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your question, here is revised answer

You can first write a function that does this for a vector

```
f <- function(x) {
    s <- sign(x)
    if (all(is.na(s))) return( c(NA, NA))
    if (all(s == -1)) return( c(NA, NA))
    mn <- min(x[which(s==-1)])
    mx <- max(x[which(s==1)])
    r <- c(mn, mx)
    r[!is.finite(r)] <- NA
    r
}
```

And test it

```
a <- c(5,-1,2)
b <- c(-5,-1,-2)
f(a)
#[1] -1  5
f(b)
#[1] NA NA
f(c(NA, NA, NA))
#[1] NA NA
f(c(0, 0, 0))
#[1] NA NA
```

There are warning that can be ignored (or turned off)
Now, with the raster data:

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
set.seed(1)    
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1), -1, 1)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2), -1, 1) / 2
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3), -1, 1) * 1.5
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)

x <- calc(s, f)
x

#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       :       layer.1,       layer.2 
#min values  : -1.3561226050,  0.0004409726 
#max values  :   -0.04476076,    1.44469038
```

Or with raster algebra, something like this:

```
pos <- reclassify(s, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA))
neg <- reclassify(s, cbind(0, Inf, NA))
xp <- max(pos, na.rm=TRUE)
nn <- min(neg, na.rm=TRUE)
nn <- mask(nn, xp)
r <- stack(nn, xp)
r
```

(I was not exactly sure how you want to deal with cells that only have the value zero, so I did not worry about that)

Comment: Thanks Robert. Sorry it seems I was not clear. what I need is assume the following case taking the corresponding pixels:  1-  `r1=5, r2=-1,r3=2 >> min=-1 and max=5`  `2- r1= -5, r2= -1,r3= -2>>min=NA and max=NA[as all of them are negative]`

Comment: If there is NA in the data, how to to modify the function f?